# Javascript - onchange image change

Tags: javascript, image

This should be fairly simple but it's not working and I'm not seeing it.  I'm trying to get my image to change with the onchange method calling the displayImage function. Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select Image</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function displayImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var newImage = image.option[image.selectedIndex].value;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="controls">
    <img id="canvas" src="pictures/fire1.jpg" />
    <select name="imageList" onchange="displayImage();">
      <option value="pictures/fire1.jpg">Fire 1</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire2.jpg">Fire 2</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire3.jpg">Fire 3</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire4.jpg">Fire 4</option>
</select>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the function being called at all? For example, if you put an alert inside displayImage(), would the alert be called? This way, you would know if it's a problem of function-not-being-called-at-all vs. function-is-called-but-not-doing-what-you-want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the image of the canvas element based on value of the dropdown list, use something like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select Image</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function displayImage(elem) {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas");
    image.src = elem.value;        
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="controls">
    <img id="canvas" src="pictures/fire1.jpg" />
    <select name="imageList" onchange="displayImage(this);">
      <option value="pictures/fire1.jpg">Fire 1</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire2.jpg">Fire 2</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire3.jpg">Fire 3</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire4.jpg">Fire 4</option>
</select>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Add `this` to the function call and modify the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function displayImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    image.src = select.value;
}
```

or more compact:

```
function displayImage() {
    document.getElementById("canvas").src = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;
}
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/21hpb2f8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
change your `select` name to `id`.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select Image</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function displayImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById("imageList").value;
    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].setAttribute("src",image)
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="controls">
    <img id="canvas" src="pictures/fire1.jpg" />
    <select id="imageList" onchange="displayImage();">
      <option value="pictures/fire1.jpg">Fire 1</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire2.jpg">Fire 2</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire3.jpg">Fire 3</option>
      <option value="pictures/fire4.jpg">Fire 4</option>
</select>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```